# Meteor - Autoform combine date and time fields after submission

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I am using autoform to generate an "event" form. On the event I have a start date, start time, end date, end time. In the database I only want to store "start" and "end" which would be the dates and times combined. I can do this manually, but I'm having no luck doing it with autoform. How do I generate fields that are not part of my schema and have those go with the "doc" to my before submission hook? Is that the best way to do this? Right now I'm trying the following:

Schema:

```
   start:
      type: Date
      label: 'Start'
   end:
      type: Date
      label: 'End'
```

Template:

```
template(name='eventsNew')
   +autoForm(collection='Events' id='insertEventForm' type='insert')
      fieldset
         legend Add an event
         +afQuickField(name='type')
         //- How do I output fields not in the schema and have them go to the form hooks? These output, but I can't get fields that are not part of the schema to work.
         +afQuickField(name='start')
         +afQuickField(name='end')
      button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
```

Form hook:

```
AutoForm.hooks 
   insertEventForm:
      before:
         insert: (doc)->
            # Here is where I would think I could combine the times and dates
            # but I can't get them to come through.
            console.log doc
            doc
```

I've tried afFieldInputs for the dates and times, but they don't generate anything. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addHooks options its only used when you want to apply the same hook to more that 1 form (an `array`), on this example you are only using 1 form (`insertEventForm`) so, the simple `hook` will be work here.

**I dont do Coffe Sorry**

Simple **JS**

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  insertEventForm:{
    before:{
     insert:function(doc){
        console.log(doc) //do more stuff here
       }
     }
  }
})
```

Comment: Ahhh nice. I will change that in the question. Thank you for that.

Comment: did you try with `doc.start = new date();` `doc.end = "another date"`?

Comment: You mean after I submit the form? I guess the first thing I need to figure out is how to generate startDate and startTime fields in the form when they are not part of the schema, and have those dates passed to the hook. I actually think that is really my main problem.

Comment: why dnt put them on the actual form, with the `optional: true`, option and lester on the road insert them on the hook or whatever

Comment: That seems to be the best solution for now. Thanks for the help.